# Convert Julia DataFrame to an array of bytes for compression

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

So I loaded two datasets from a csv and then merged them using a `leftjoin`:

```
using CSV
using DataFrames
using CodecZstd

df1 = CSV.read(joinpath(root, "data", "raw", "df1.csv"), DataFrame)
df2 = CSV.read(joinpath(root, "data", "raw", "df2.csv"), DataFrame)

merged = leftjoin(df1, df2, on=:id)
```

Now I want to write the merged dataframe to disk as a `.zst` compressed file (Zstandard compression).

I was successful in first writing to `.csv` then reading then writing again as `.zst` but is there a way to directly convert a `DataFrame` into an array of bytes to be able to save to disk?

Comment: Zstandard does not define a rectangular data format: it's just a way to compress binary data. You will have to choose some serialized representation of the DataFrame first and then compress that using Zstandard. If compressing a CSV via something like [CodecZstd.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/CodecZstd.jl) does not meet your needs, then can you tell us specifically why?

Comment: I understand that. "You will have to choose some serialized representation of the DataFrame first". Well, how? That's what I'm asking in the title. How to serialize a DataFrame in order to compress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options. The one built-in into Julia is to serialize a data frame. You can achieve this by using the `Serialialization` standard library. It offers two functions `serialize` for serialization of streams and `deserialize` for their deserialization. Then you can use CodecZstd.jl to compress the serialized stream and save it to disk.

Note that when you use serialization it is your responsibility to ensure that the Julia and package versions are consistent between the Julia session where you write data and where you read your data.

Comment: Thank you!! Could you please elaborate on the last point? Am I able to send the compressed file to a colleague even if we're using different versions of Julia and packages?

Comment: Standard Julia serialization is system, Julia, and package version specific. So it might work (and usually will work), but is not guaranteed to work (for example if internal representation of objects changes; e.g. in Julia 1.11 there will be a change in how `Array` type is implemented internally, so serialization between Julia 1.10 and 1.11 will not work). As Przemysław mentioned in the other answer, if you want portability you should use standard data intechange formats instead of raw binary representation. Examples of such formats are Arrow.jl or Parquet2.jl.

Answer (score 5):

To follow precisely your questions you can do:

```
using CSV, DataFrames, CodecZstd
fout = ZstdCompressorStream(open("z.zst","w"))
df = DataFrame(a='a':'h', b=1:8)
CSV.write(df ,fout)
close(fout)
```

Now this can be read as:

```
julia> CSV.read(ZstdDecompressorStream(open("z.zst")), DataFrame)
8×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a        b
     │ String1  Int64
─────┼────────────────
   1 │ a            1
   2 │ b            2
   3 │ c            3
   4 │ d            4
   5 │ e            5
   6 │ f            6
   7 │ g            7
   8 │ h            8
```

Other reasonable option would be to use Apache Arrow to write the DataFrame instead of CSV. The compression would compose in the same ways as above.